# SpriteKit missing linear transformation matrices

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, transformation, cgaffinetransform, sknode

Does anyone know how to transform (**rotate**,**scale**,**skew**) SpriteKit nodes using transformation matrices. couldn't find any support for this in the Spritekit API.

Comment: I'm not sure about it specifically but you can add an SKEffectNode to a node and the effects that can be run are any of the CIFilters (or your own) that are available on iOS.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by [Fogmeister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421018/fogmeister), you can use an SKEffectNode with a CIFilter. The following works on iOS:

```
// Label
let label = SKLabelNode(text: "Hello world")
// Transform
let transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0.5, 0, 1, 0, 0)
// CIFilter
let transformFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineTransform")!
let val = NSValue(CGAffineTransform: transform)
transformFilter.setValue(val, forKey: "inputTransform")
// Effect node
let transformNode = SKEffectNode()
transformNode.filter = transformFilter
// Add label as child on effect node
transformNode.addChild(label)
scene.addChild(transformNode)
```

See more on affine transform in Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH204-SW1).